# Routing rewrite base on addon domain account

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been trying different configurations on my routing `.htacces` to make it work, but I am completely lost, since I'm no expert in apache at all.

The problem is that I want to create a simple routing system to pass the url as a GET, and what I've done works perfectly when I'm playing around locally or in domains such as example.com So for example, example.com/hello, I could catch that hello from GET.

But when I want to upload it on the server I have to use, it doesn't have a domain associated yet, so the url looks like **example.com/~account/**
I'm also not sure about how this kind of url is called, I don't think I'm using the correct terms.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /testapp/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

( That rewritebase rule is the one I use locally localhost/testapp/public )
I'm not sure if its clear enough..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Such URL has nothing to do with the fact that "the server does not yet have a domain". Such URL points to the public_html folder inside your user accounts home directory on the server.

Comment: Alright, so then, the RewriteBase should be just '/'? since it's pointing at public_html? Everything after `~account/` should be parsed as a `GET`.